# Scrolling does not work when responsive bootstrap navbar is extended to full size

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, scroll

I just started with ROR and I'm following the One Month Rails tutorial. This includes the Bootstrap responsive navbar. I now added some pins to my pinterest clone. I noticed that the scrolling does not work when the navbar is in full size. when i make the browserwindow smaller so the navigation gets into the small navigation symbol i can scroll the page. You can probably see best on my heroku link: morning-shore-7790.herokuapp.com

It would be great to get a hint on how to solve this.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've nested the container class inside the navbar, which will always cause this behavior.

If you're using ERB it means you didn't close a div where you should have, if you're using haml or slim it's most likely an indentation oops.  If you use chrome, safari or firefox you can see this clearly, just inspect the element and collapse the navbar, if all other content is contained within that, you still haven't fixed it.

If you still have questions post your layout and your index.

Comment: you're a genius! that bothered me the whole day. i forgot to close a div in the header file. Now scrolling works perfectly :) now i just have to figure out why it doesn't show the boxes arround the pins. thanks a lot!